# c++ missing endianconvert method

Tags: c++, endianness

I have some partial source code which I'm trying to fully reconstruct (don't ask where the rest is, its not available) and I'm currently stuck at a missing method 'endianconvert'

I don't have much experience with c++ so I'm hoping someone here can help me out. heres the function call

```
endianConvert (reinterpret_cast<DWORD *>(pData+dwClassOffset), sizeof (PageTable) >> 2);
```

pData is a BYTE array filled with the contents of a file

```
BYTE * pData = new BYTE[l];
```

dwclassoffset is the current location in the file

```
DWORD dwClassOffset = 0;
```

and PageTable is a class containing several DWORD variables.

It it looks like I need to swap the endianess of several DWORDS in the BYTE array but I don't know how to start implementing this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>> 2` expression divides the size of the object in bytes by 4, which gives you the number of 4-byte words to convert, so start with a function that does *something* that many times:

```
void endianConvert(DWORD* data, size_t count)
{
    for (size_t n = 0; n < count; ++n)
       /* convert data[n] */;
}
```

Now you need to be able to swap the endianness of a single DWORD, which is quite simple:

```
DWORD& d = data[n];
DWORD b1 = d & 0x000000ff;
DWORD b2 = d & 0x0000ff00;
DWORD b3 = d & 0x00ff0000;
DWORD b4 = d & 0xff000000;
d = (b1 << 24) | (b2 << 8) | (b3 >> 8) | (b4 >> 24);
```

Extract each byte, then shift it to the position it would have in the other endianness, and OR the bytes together.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably the `endianConvert` function converts 32-bit integer values from the file into 32-bit integer values in memory. To implement it, you should know which endian is used in the file and also which endian is used on the target machine. If their endians are the same, then `endianConvert` should just leave the array as is, otherwise it should do something like

```
uint32_t dw = *dword_ptr;
// flip bytes
dw = (dw >> 24) | ((dw >> 8) & 0xff00) | ((dw << 8) & 0xff0000) | (dw << 24);
*dword_ptr = dw;
```

for every DWORD in the array.

Comment: Thanks, the file is big endian and the machine is little endian if it makes a difference.